# Reluctant quantifier and Positive lookahead in POSIX regex

Tags: regex, posix, reluctant-quantifiers

I was trying to use a reluctant quantifier (.*?) but that does not seem to work in POSIX regex. Doesn't POSIX support reluctant quantifiers? If not, are there any alternatives. I was also not able to get a positive lookahead work in POSIX. Is it also not supported? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your real issue? POSIX regex flavor does not support lookarounds, nor reluctant quantifiers. A workaround might exist for  a particular case or not.

Comment: can you comment on which library you used? your sample regex

Answer (score 1):

Lookaround and non-greedy quantifiers are Perl regex features. They don't exist in POSIX.

As for alternatives, workarounds may be possible but it depends on what exactly you're trying to match. There's no general solution.